# Angular circular dependency: Component uses service to dynamically create a component of the same type

Tags: angular

I have a Graph component where I can add nodes dynamically. I have outsourced the addition of nodes to a GraphService to be able to trigger the addition of nodes by clicking on them.

Unfortunately, this results in a circular dependency between the Nodes component and the NodesService.

**GraphService** contains:

```
let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(NodeComponent);
```

and **NodeComponent** contains **GraphService** in the constructor:

```
constructor(
    private graphService: GraphService
) {}
```

My goal is to be able to trigger the addition of nodes by clicking on a button on a node itself. Should I use an own component to encapsulate the button or is there a better and cleaner solution for this issue?

If more comprehensive code is needed, I'll be happy to provide it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by removing the GraphService from the NodeComponent. I just created a third component NodeControls and placed the GraphService in its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use dynamic injection:

```js
class NodeComponent {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  someMethod() {
    const graphServiceInstance = this.injector.get<GraphService>(GraphService);
  }
}
```